# Using lme4/R: calculating OR from glmer output

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to calculate Odds Ratios from `glmer` output in R.
My model is called `gmE2` and I am using the following formula:

```
confint(gmE2,parm="beta_")
```

I keep getting the following error message and unsure why:

> Error in zeta(shiftpar, start = opt[seqpar1][-w]) : 
>     profiling detected new, lower deviance

Can anybody help!?

PS - when running `gmE2` it runs but I do get the following message (unsure if this is impacting the ability to calculate OR?:

> Warning messages:
>
> In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>     Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0963262 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
>
> In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>     Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
>    - Rescale variables?

Comment: For coefficients you can just use `exp(fixef(lme_mod))` and for confidence intervals `exp(confint(lme_mod))`

Comment: Thanks @tmfmnk! I tried that although I am still getting the error message " Error in zeta(shiftpar, start = opt[seqpar1][-w]) : 
  profiling detected new, lower deviance"

Comment: I'll keep trying some different ways!

Comment: probably too late, but I don't think the question can be answered without a [mcve] ...